# Conditional sort in XSL

Tags: sorting, xslt

I have a XML file transformed in HTML with XSLT 1.0, but I'd like to sort data according to a user choice. I set a variable in PHP for the choice, it's works, but I don't know how to make this conditional sort.

Here my code with the variable $sort_by :

```
        <xsl:for-each select="gpx:gpx/gpx:wpt">
         <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$sort_by = 'name'">
              <xsl:sort select="grdspk:cache/grdspk:name"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$sort_by = 'owner'">
              <xsl:sort select="grdspk:cache/grdspk:owner"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$sort_by = 'difficulty'">
              <xsl:sort select="grdspk:cache/grdspk:difficulty"/>
          </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
```

This code doesn't work, I have a compilation error "element sort is not allowed within that context".

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the variable as part of the XPath for the `xsl:sort` select criteria

```
<xsl:for-each select="gpx:gpx/gpx:wpt">
    <xsl:sort select="grdspk:cache/grdspk:*[local-name()=$sort_by]"/>
    <!--additional logic goes here-->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I just added the translate function for ignore case : 

`<xsl:sort select="translate(grdspk:cache/grdspk:*[local-name()=$sort_by], 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')"/>`